# Google Maps cannot add markers after I remove them

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-maps-api-2

I created a map using Google Maps. I have a list of locations and each location has geolocation that helps me to create a marker with.

I want that each time I click a list item, to remove the current markers that are on the map and to add new ones.

This is the way that I add markers on the map:

```
 foreach (var postOffice in ViewModel.PostOfficeList)
 {
      var markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
      markerOptions.SetPosition(new LatLng(postOffice.Location.Lat, postOffice.Location.Lng));
      markerOptions.SetTitle(postOffice.Name);
      markerOptions.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.post_office_selected));
      if (postOffice.IsHighlighted)
      {
            markerOptions.SetAlpha(1);
      }
      else
      {
            markerOptions.SetAlpha(0.5f);
      }
      var marker = _mapView.AddMarker(markerOptions);
      _markerList.Add(marker);
 }
```

Before I access this, I call the function that removes my markers from the list:

```
private void RemoveMarkers()
{
    foreach (var marker in _markerList)
    {
        marker.Remove();
        marker.Dispose();
    }
    _markerList.Clear();
}
```

What actually happens is that the first time I access the map, all the markers are in place but when I try to refresh the markers, all the markers are removed from the list and are not added back.

I tried also to clear the map with `_mapView.Clear()` but nothing happened.

Comment: Why exactly are you doing the above here? Hopefully to clear the markers if yes why not just `MapView.Clear`

Comment: Yes, as I said, I used _mapView.Clear() but nothing happened. After that, I tried to remove manually all the markers.

Comment: I am curious are you trying to do this on page load?

Comment: No, I want to remove the markers when I click on a button from the page.

Comment: So when you do clear it after that you are unable to add at all is it? And also how do you re add them

Comment: How did you solve it?